# Using String to find Class in java?

Tags: java, string, class

I have made a class named Entity, and have the following code:

```
Entity zombie1 = new Entity();
```

I get input 'zombie' from a scanner, and then concatenate a number, based on level on the end of that, leaving 'zombie1' as the string... I want to be able to use that string and call

```
zombie1.shoot("shotgun");
```

but I can't seem to find a solution. I'd just do a if statement but I want to be able to create as many zombies as I want and not have to put in more if statements every single time.

I've read articles using reflection and forString but that doesn't seem to be what i'm looking for.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: String is an class made by default, There are no such .shoot method in it! however, You may try to extend entity class by String class and add method to it! NOT TESTED need more professional advice on this.

Answer (score 3):

Possible solutions are to use a `Map<String, Entity>` to be able to store and retrieve entities based on specific Strings.  If you have a limited number of sub-types of Entity such as Zombies, Vampires, Victims, etc, you could have a `Map<String, List<Entity>>`, allowing you to map a String to a specific type of entity and then get that type by number.

e.g.,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Foo002 {
   private static final String ZOMBIE = "zombie";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Map<String, List<Entity>> entityMap = new HashMap<String, List<Entity>>();

      entityMap.put(ZOMBIE, new ArrayList<Entity>());

      entityMap.get(ZOMBIE).add(new Entity(ZOMBIE, "John"));
      entityMap.get(ZOMBIE).add(new Entity(ZOMBIE, "Fred"));
      entityMap.get(ZOMBIE).add(new Entity(ZOMBIE, "Bill"));

      for (Entity entity : entityMap.get(ZOMBIE)) {
         System.out.println(entity);
      }
   }
}

class Entity {
   private String type;
   private String name;

   public Entity(String type, String name) {
      this.type = type;
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getType() {
      return type;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return type + ": " + name;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not your best bet. Your best bet is to have a Map;

```
// PLEASE LOOK INTO WHICH MAP WOULD BE BEST FOR YOUR CASE OVERALL
// HASHMAP IS JUST AN EXAMPLE.
Map<String, Entity> zombieHoard = new HashMap<String, Entity>;

String getZombieID( int id )
{
    return String.format( "zombie%s", id );
}
String createZombie() {
    String zid = getZombieID( Map.size() );
    Map.put( zid, new Entity() );
    return zid;
}

void sendForthTheHoard() {
   createZombie();
   createZombie();
   String currentZombie = createZombie();
   zombieHoard.get( currentZombie ).shoot( "blow-dryer" );
   zombieHoard.get( getZombieID( 1 ) ).eatBrains();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your zombies in an ArrayList. Example:

```
ArrayList<Entity> zombies = new ArrayList<Entity>();
Entity zombie1 = new Entity();
zombies.add(zombie1);
Entity zombie2 = new Entity();
zombies.add(zombie2);
etc...
```

Then when it is time to call a certain zombie to the following:

```
zombies.get(1).shoot("shotgun");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about dynamically invoking a method on an object, you can use Reflection to get the method object and invoke it (Note: I may have inadvertantly mixed up some C# syntax in this Java):

```
Entity zombie1 = new Entity();
Method shootMethod = Entity.class.getMethod("shoot", new Class[] { string.class });
shootMethod.invoke(zombie1, new Object[] { "shotgun" });
```